Pole of inaccessibility and buffer loop using PyQGIS
I'm trying to create a Python script in QGIS that will identify potential sites for tree planting in residential areas.
The logic is:

Start with a layer "trn_fts_roadtrackorpath" that contains polygons of pavements
Run poleofinaccessibility to identify that largest circle that will fit in each pavement polygon
Retain only those with a dist_pole>1.5
Buffer those points by dist_pole
Cut out those buffered points from trn_fts_roadtrackorpath
Loop back to 2 and continue until there no points with dist_pole>1.5 found.

My code is below but gives an error

Could not load source layer for INPUT: Point_8fc95314_ccbd_4c9b_98b2_f809086d5174 not found

on the line buffered_poles = processing.run("qgis:buffer", {
Why do I get this error and how I fix it?
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

def process_inaccessible_poles(layer_name, tolerance, min_distance):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    while True:
        # 1. Identify Inaccessible Poles
        poles = processing.run("qgis:poleofinaccessibility", {
            'INPUT': layer,
            'TOLERANCE': tolerance,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']

        # 2. Filter Out Close Poles
        filtered_poles = processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
            'INPUT': poles,
            'EXPRESSION': "\"dist_pole\" > {}".format(min_distance),
            'METHOD': 0
        })['OUTPUT']
        keeppnts = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(filtered_poles.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid)
        # 3. Buffer Remaining Poles
        buffered_poles = processing.run("qgis:buffer", {
            'INPUT': keeppnts,
            'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression('"dist_pole"'),
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffered_poles)
        # 4. Difference the Road Network
        clipped_layer = processing.run("qgis:difference", {
            'INPUT': layer,
            'OVERLAY': buffered_poles,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']

        # 5. Check for Iteration
        selected_features = processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
            'INPUT': clipped_layer,
            'EXPRESSION': "\"dist_pole\" > {}".format(min_distance),
            'METHOD': 0
        })['OUTPUT']

        if selected_features.featureCount() =0:
            break

        # Update the layer for the next iteration (Option 2)
        layer_id = layer.id()
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer_id)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clipped_layer)
        layer = clipped_layer

# Parameters:
layer_name = "trn_fts_roadtrackorpath"
tolerance = 0.01
min_distance = 1.5

process_inaccessible_poles(layer_name, tolerance, min_distance)


Which line is giving the error

It's the line beginning "buffered_poles= ..." in step 3. If I run some of the sections without the loop it works for one iteration, so wondered if it's something to do with not finding points on the second iteration. Sorry I'm a newbie at Python in QGIS.

Thanks. That return 140 so that part works. I tried added a similar statement after "keeppnts = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(filtered_poles.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid)" but it never reaches it so it's that keeppoint = ... statement that is causing the problem.

In addition to @Matt's answer, another option could be use Extract By Expression instead with a memory layer output which you can pass as input to the Buffer alg.

There are a couple of issues with the following line of code in your question:
if selected_features.featureCount() =0:
    break

=0 will throw a syntax error. It should be == 0.
Even with that correction, the if statement will never evaluate to True. The selected_features variable references the original layer, not the selected features of that layer. Every iteration you are checking if the clipped_layer has features, resulting in an infinite loop.
Use instead:
if selected_features.selectedFeatureCount() == 0:
    break

To address the error you are encountering, it seems that the poles layer must be added to the map for the selection to be recognised (or indeed filtered_poles, as they reference the same in-memory output).
def process_inaccessible_poles(layer_name, tolerance, min_distance):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    while True:
        # 1. Identify Inaccessible Poles
        poles = processing.run("qgis:poleofinaccessibility", {
            'INPUT': layer,
            'TOLERANCE': tolerance,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']

        # ----- add this line -----
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(poles)

        # 2. Filter Out Close Poles
        filtered_poles = processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
            'INPUT': poles,
            'EXPRESSION': "\"dist_pole\" > {}".format(min_distance),
            'METHOD': 0
        })['OUTPUT']        
        
        keeppnts = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(filtered_poles.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid)
        # 3. Buffer Remaining Poles
        buffered_poles = processing.run("qgis:buffer", {
            'INPUT': keeppnts,
            'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression('"dist_pole"'),
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffered_poles)
        # 4. Difference the Road Network
        clipped_layer = processing.run("qgis:difference", {
            'INPUT': layer,
            'OVERLAY': buffered_poles,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })['OUTPUT']

        # 5. Check for Iteration
        selected_features = processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
            'INPUT': clipped_layer,
            'EXPRESSION': "\"dist_pole\" > {}".format(min_distance),
            'METHOD': 0
        })['OUTPUT']

        if selected_features.selectedFeatureCount() == 0:
            break

        # Update the layer for the next iteration (Option 2)
        layer_id = layer.id()
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer_id)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clipped_layer)
        layer = clipped_layer



Another issue is that you are making a selection on clipped_layer using the "dist_pole" attribute. But the clipped_layer never has this attribute - the difference tool does not assign attributes of the overlay layer to the input layer. The number of selected features is therefore always 0.
